# Jackson Deserializer default to null on failure

Tags: java, kotlin, jackson

I have an issue where an upstream service is making requests and about 5% of the requests that are made are partially malformed. For example, instead of a nullable property coming to me as the object type I am expecting, I get a random string.

```kotlin
data class FooDTO(
  val bar: BarDTO?,
  val name: String
)

data class BarDTO(
  val size: Int
)
```

But the payload I get looks like

```json
{
  "name": "The Name",
  "bar": "uh oh random string instead of object"
}
```

I don't want to fail the request when this happens because the part of the data that is correct is still useful for my purposes, so what I want to do is just default the deserialization failure to `null`. I also have a few different sub-objects in my `FooDTO` that do this so I want a generic way to solve it for those specific fields. I know I can write a custom deserializer like the following to solve it on a 1-off basis.

```kotlin
class BarDtoDeserializer @JvmOverloads constructor(vc: Class<*>? = null) : StdDeserializer<BarDTO?>(vc) {
    override fun deserialize(jp: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext): AnalysisDTO? {
        return try {
            val node = jp.codec.readTree<JsonNode>(jp)
            BarDTO(size = node.get("size").numberValue().toInt())
        } catch (ex: Throwable) {
            null
        }
    }
}
```

And then I can decorate my `BarDTO` object with a `@JsonDeserialize(using=BarDtoDeserializer::class)` to force it to use that deserializer. What I am hoping to do is have some way to do this in a generic way.

Comment: Is it possible to override the responsible method in a central deserializer, instead of using the customized deserializer only for this one parameter? So instead of `BarDtoDeserializer`, using a `GeneralDtoDeserializer` and then catching class cast exceptions on value assignment (and then defaulting to null instead).

Comment: Do the payloads you receive contain any uniquely identifiable fields? For example, one contains `"id": "foo"` or `"foo-based-id": 3`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45484422/4161471 I've found that a [`DeserializationProblemHandler`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/DeserializationProblemHandler.html) can be used to return 'null' for invalid data.

In your instance, override the `handleMissingInstantiator()` function. If other payloads have other types of bad data, other overrides may be required.

Also, I thought that [`CoercionConfig`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/CoercionConfig.html) might be the answer, but I couldn't get it to work or find decent documentation. That might be another path.

---

```kotlin
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializationProblemHandler
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.jacksonObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.readValue


data class FooDTO(
  val name: String,
  val bar: BarDTO?,
)

data class BarDTO(
  val size: Int
)

fun main() {
  val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()

//  mapper
//    .coercionConfigFor(LogicalType.Textual)
//    .setCoercion(CoercionInputShape.String, CoercionAction.AsNull)

  mapper.addHandler(object : DeserializationProblemHandler() {
    override fun handleMissingInstantiator(
      ctxt: DeserializationContext?,
      instClass: Class<*>?,
      valueInsta: ValueInstantiator?,
      p: JsonParser?,
      msg: String?
    ): Any? {
      println("returning null for value, $msg")
      return null
    }
  })

  val a: FooDTO = mapper.readValue(
    """
      {
        "name": "I'm variant A",
        "bar": "uh oh random string instead of object"
      }
    """
  )
  val b: FooDTO = mapper.readValue(
    """
      {
        "name": "I'm variant B",
        "bar": {
          "size": 2     
        }
      }
    """
  )

  println(a)
  println(b)
  assert(a.bar == null)
  assert(a.bar?.size == 2)

}
```

Output:

```
returning null for value, no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('uh oh random string instead of object')
FooDTO(name=I'm variant A, bar=null)
FooDTO(name=I'm variant B, bar=BarDTO(size=2))

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: This absolutely worked for me. What I ended up doing was adding a companion object with a list of classes that I wanted to default to null that contained `BarDTO` and then in the `handleMissingInstantiator` override, I just check `return if(instClass in DEFAULT_TO_NULL_CLASSES) null else super.handleMissingInstantiator(ctxt, instClass, valueInsta, p, msg)`